# How to change the font of an email?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe3

I am using `TidSmtp` and `TidMessage` in Delphi XE3 for sending mail:

```
Idmessage1.body := StringList;
Smtp.Send(IDmessage1);
```

How to change the font of `Idmessage1`?

Comment: A `TStringList` doesn't have a `font`, so there's nothing to change. If you're sending HTML format mail, you would set the font in the HTML content just as you would normally.

Comment: Same with RTF formatted email.